# React-Native, React-Native-Web and React-Navigation/Stack

Tags: react-native, react-native-web, react-navigation-v6

Has anyone been able to get React-Native 0.7, React-Native-Web and React-Navigation/Stack 6.2.3 to work on web? I have a small app working on iOS and Android which I am trying to enable on web too. iOS and Android portion work fine and using metro.

However, webpack build continues to error out with "Module parse failed: Unexpected token" on the NavigationContainer.

I tried searching both react-native-web and react-navigation Issues on their respective GitHub Repositories. However, could not find something to solve my issue. Also tried modifying webpack.config with several different configurations/loaders.

Used links below as a reference too:
https://arry.medium.com/how-to-add-react-native-web-to-an-existing-react-native-project-eb98c952c12f
https://gist.github.com/skabbes/0bfa0a969aac8ec13f716dda1ad2ab43

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it happens that I maintain a library that does just that: creates a bare React Native app that also runs on the web:  Luna -  https://github.com/criszz77/luna

Here is the live example: https://criszz77.github.io/luna/

You can find more on the wiki page about how it's implemented and you can also implement it by yourself: https://github.com/criszz77/luna/wiki

By using `react-scripts`, you don't have to handle webpack, babel and other hard configs by yourself.

It currently doesn't run on 0.7 (didn't have time to make the update), but it's in plan to support all the latest versions of course ASAP.

EDIT: Updated to **0.70.3**

Comment: updated wiki link